# How to generate graphs as in Android ICS data usage settings

Tags: android, graph, settings, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I wanted to know if android sdk provides any built in components(views) for the specific graphs as seen in the ICS setting screen as follows :

[image]  [image]

If not then what can be the best way to go for such graph component. Any library suggested ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, luckily Android is open source, so I imagine you can grab the source and look through the settings app to figure out how they achieve it:

http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Comment: Well, I digged the code and came to a conclusion that I'll have to write my custom view for that as seen in android. Thanks @Chandra Sekhar too.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no default API for this from Android. You have to implement your own custom View for this.